# Why does data import in R with fread function cause a peculiar datatype comparison bug, leading to further filtering issues

Tags: r, types, data.table, fread

I am using data.table::fread to import a large dataset with 7.5 million rows and 56 columns.
I specify variable classes for certain variables to be read as character using colClasses argument.
Data looks fine after importing, and column classes are correctly made.

However, issues start to occur when I filter the data. Unfortunately, I can't construct an example here because I don't know exactly what the problem is.

But basically bugs occur when I use binary logic to filter some rows.

#### Below codes show the bug:

First of all 'id' column is read as character and str/glimpse/class/mode all confirm it. Then why does this happen:

```
mydata[mydata$id == 01005845, year]
[1] 2015 2014 2013 2012

mydata[mydata$id == "01005845", year]
[1] 2011 2010 2009 2008 2007 2006 2005
```

To further test I rechecked the data class for these specific observations, which still shows as character:

```
typeof(mydata[mydata$id == 01005845, id])
[1] "character"

glimpse(mydata[mydata$id == 01005845, id])
chr [1:4] "01005845" "01005845" "01005845" "01005845"

mydata[mydata$id == 01005845, id] == 01005845
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

This does not make any sense to me because for some other id's all types are character and I don't get this weird result.

All in all this character - integer comparison inconsistency messes up all my analysis. My filterings do not work out correctly and the output gets affected badly.

I appreciate all your help.
Take care :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that is because `01005845 != "01005845"`

If you type `01005845` in the console, you get

```
>01005845
#[1] 1005845
```

01005845 is a number and the 0's at the beginning of the number do not hold any significance, hence it is stripped off. This issue is not related to `data.table` or `fread` but a general issue on how numbers are handled.

Since `id` column is character, you should use

```
mydata[id == "01005845", year]
```

---

This small example demonstrates the issue

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(a = c('2011', '02011', '2011', '2012', '02011'), b = letters[1:5])

df[a == 02011, ]
#      a b
#1: 2011 a
#2: 2011 c

df[a == "02011", ]
#       a b
#1: 02011 b
#2: 02011 e
```

Comment: @MuhammetCoskun Can you check `sum(mydata$id == "1005845")` and then `sum(mydata$id == "01005845")`. Followed by `which(mydata$id == "1005845")` and `which(mydata$id == "01005845")`

Comment: I see your point and it makes sense. However, my main problem occurs when I use group_by function from dplyr package because then these number-like id rows are grouped as different from others. How can I avoid this?

Comment: If you want `1005845` should be in the same group as `01005845`, convert them to numeric. do `mydata %>% group_by(id = as.numeric(id)) ..... rest of the chain`.